# How to use stored function(procedure) in where clause?(Entity Framework Core 2.0)

Tags: stored-procedures, entity-framework-core

How to use stored procedure in where clause ?! Stored procedure retrieve integer.

```
select a, b, c, d 
from a1 
where procedure(a, b, c) > 0
```

Comment: Simple: **you CANNOT** do this. Period. You might be able to use a stored **function** - but **NOT** a stored procedure

Comment: ok , when use stored function how to implement on c#

Comment: Take a look at [Database Scalar Function Mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.0#database-scalar-function-mapping).